# SVG clipPath в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, анимация

Хочу сделать из фотографии одной картины модульную картину из 5 частей с помощью `clipPath`.
Как бы получается, но в адаптивной верстке все едет: картинка адаптируется, части нет.
Как зафиксировать картинку в каждой части при изменении размера окна?

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/31565/

```css
.modular{clip-path:url(#modular)}
.modular{max-height: 80vh; max-width: 100%; display: block; margin: 15px auto;}
```

```html
<img class="modular" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GsPE7.jpg" alt="Модульная картина"/>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="modular">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="500" />
      <rect x="210" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="410" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="610" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="810" y="0" width="190" height="500" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: интересный вопрос, хорошо оформлен.

Comment: А бутстрап-то тут при чём?

Comment: @ Qwertiy  бутстрап у него в проекте, но это в данном решении не имеет значения, можно добавлять куда угодно, везде будет работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы приложение было адаптивно и не разрушались пропорции между фрагментами изображения необходимо сделать следующее:

- Изображение добавить внутрь svg с помощью команды `<image>` и задать
  размеры его в процентах `width="100%" height="100"`
- Окна вырезать комбинированной маской. При присвоении одним частям
  маски `fill="white"` она будет прозрачна и в вырезанных окошках будут
  видны фрагменты изображения.  Закраска `fill="black"` делает участок
  маски непрозрачным - это белые перемычки между окнами.
- Обернуть svg  `<div class="container">` в родительский контейнер. Изменяя проценты
  ширины и высоты контейнера можно регулировать начальные размеры
  блока.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" > 
 <defs>
    <mask id="modular">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
  <g fill="white">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="500" />
      <rect x="210" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="410" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="610" y="0" width="180" height="500" />
      <rect x="810" y="0" width="190" height="500" />  
   </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>    

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ZDz.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#modular)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Приложение полностью адаптивно и работает во всех браузерах**

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант с анимацией при наведении курсора на картинку

- При наведении курсора на картинку фрагменты изображения сливаются в
  целое изображение.

Это обеспечивает команда анимации добавленная в маску:

`<animate attributeName="x" values="210;189" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive"  fill="freeze" />`

Реализация смещения фрагмента изображения (секции маски) осуществляется изменением координаты левого верхнего угла прямоугольника - `X` `values="210;189"`

- При уходе курсора с картинки, изображение возвращается к исходному
  состоянию :

  `<animate attributeName="x" values="189;210" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />`

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  > 
 <defs>
    <mask id="modular">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
  <g fill="white">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="500" />
      <rect x="210" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
    <animate attributeName="x" values="210;189" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive"  fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeName="x" values="189;210" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
   </rect>
      <rect x="410" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
   <animate attributeName="x" values="410;360" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
   <animate attributeName="x" values="360;410" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
      <rect x="610" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
   <animate attributeName="x" values="610;535" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive"  fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate attributeName="x" values="535;610" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
      <rect x="810" y="0" width="190" height="500" >
<animate attributeName="x" values="810;710" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
 <animate attributeName="x" values="710;810" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>   
   </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>    

<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ZDz.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#modular)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

### Вариант анимации с кликом

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  > 
 <defs>
    <mask id="modular">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
  <g fill="white">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="500" />
      <rect x="210" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
    <animate attributeName="x" values="210;189" dur="1s" begin="img1.click"  fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeName="x" values="189;210" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
   </rect>
      <rect x="410" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
   <animate attributeName="x" values="410;360" dur="1s" begin="img1.click"  fill="freeze" />
   <animate attributeName="x" values="360;410" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
      <rect x="610" y="0" width="180" height="500" >
   <animate attributeName="x" values="610;535" dur="1s" begin="img1.click"  fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate attributeName="x" values="535;610" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
      <rect x="810" y="0" width="190" height="500" >
<animate attributeName="x" values="810;710" dur="1s" begin="img1.click" fill="freeze" />
 <animate attributeName="x" values="710;810" dur="1s" begin="img1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>   
   </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>    

<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ZDz.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#modular)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```